# How to populate lookup field dynamically in client side

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, lookup, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I'm using dynamics crm 2016, my mission is to copy a record in client side (no plugins) so using onload event I'm calling a function that fetching an object with all my attributes(to be copy to..), I can fill simply all fields in my form except from lookup field. I have in my data from my fetch 3 values to use: 
name: the data shown in the field' 
value: the guid of the entity reference and a number of type..
To populate a lookup field I need the name of the entity the id and type.
***THE code needs to be generic
Two questions rise up:

**1**.Is the type value usable to populate the entity type field if yes then how?
**2**.Can I populate the name attribute in the new field as is from the old field?

Example of the data that I get :

```
Attributes
:
name
:
"this is the name"
type
:
"10026"  -- Can I get the entity name (Account,Contact etc...) according to this val?
__proto__
:
Object
Value
:
"{6BddfDC-8B10-47F4-BC49-A537d2E43E}"
```

Comment: I understand that I need to query the metadata to get the entity name according to entityType, so If someone has a simple Idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure from where you are getting the entity type code aka `objecttypecode` (10026), you may need to change the source to store entity type name (logical name). Since the object array used to store lookup value **expects** guid, display name & type like `[{ id: recordid, name: recordName, entityType: entityName }]`. Otherwise like you commented you need to pull from Metadata or store some key:value pairs as enums.
2. You can get all the needed properties from old field & set to new field like below.

-

```
var lookupObjValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(old_lookupSchemaName).getValue();

var lookupEntityType = lookupObjValue[0].entityType, //To get EntityName
lookupRecordGuid = lookupObjValue[0].id, // To get record GUID
lookupRecordName = lookupObjValue[0].name; //To get record Name 

Xrm.Page.getAttribute(new_lookupSchemaName).setValue([{ id: lookupRecordGuid, name: lookupRecordName, entityType: lookupEntityType }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, after investigating I found out that my prob is to get the entityname from web.api that part was missing, looking for a full example how to use CRM web api

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is no code (plugins) to me it seems a bit of a cheat to use JavaScript to achieve the same.

You should investigate how much of this could be done using a CRM Workflow, making a solution that would be supportable by a functional support person rather than a technical.

You could then optionally trigger the workflow using JavaScript