# How to populate look up field based on text field - Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to populate contact field (Potential Customer) based on text field (Email Address) set. To bear in mind, it should be unique based on the customer record.

Condition is if Email address field is set, look up field (Potential Customer) value should be fetched based on the Email address field.

[image]

Comment: Was my answer helpful? pls mark/upvote the answer to help other community members finding it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are trying to fill that contact lookup from (plugin, form script, console job, web app, ETL, MS Flow, etc), you have to fetch the contact by filtering the email value and set it in lookup entity reference.

You can use web api or fetchxml to achieve that. Here is how it should look like.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?$select=fullname&$filter=emailaddress1 eq 'test@gmail.com'
```

[C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61314598/7920473)

[Javascript example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402208/7920473)

Comment: I am new to this so not sure how to use web api or fetchxml. Could you please guide me through.

Comment: @LogeeVaghela it depends on where you’re using your code.  You can find lot of examples Online and in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @LogeeVaghela you can start here - https://carldesouza.com/set-retrieve-id-lookup-value-using-xrmwebapi/

Comment: @LogeeVaghela Do you have follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

Once you fetch the lookup field based on email address using web api which is suggested by Arun. To set lookup field on form using javascript see below article.
https://xrmdynamicscrm.wordpress.com/2020/06/17/dynamics-crm-365-set-lookup-regarding-field-while-using-xrm-navigation-openform-formparameters/

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful